# Can vectors be "more" collinear than others?

Tags: vectors

Suppose I had vectors $$\mathbf{a} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} \mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} \mathbf{c} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

(The specific numbers in the vectors don't matter, only the axes they exist on). Would it make sense, or be at all correct to say that $\mathbf{b}$ is "more collinear" with $\mathbf{a}$ than with $\mathbf{c}$ because they are on more of the same axes? And if not, is there a way to describe what I'm talking about?

Comment: You can compute the angle between those vectors.

Comment: True, you could say the cosine distance is smaller between more similar vectors, but what is the word for the similarity here? Is it correct to say they're "strongly colinear" or does it not make sense to use the word "colinear" in that way

Comment: I have never heard anything like that, it doesn't really make sense to use the word "collinear" here.

Comment: I would say that in the $a-c$ subspace, $\mathbf b$ is preferentially aligned along $\mathbf a$

Comment: @Andrei that sounds like what I'm looking for. Could you point me to a definition of preferential alignment? Google is no help

Comment: I have this for a physics definition https://dictionary.iucr.org/Preferred_orientation

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the angle between the two directions using scalar product. In fact use $$\cos^2\theta=\frac{(\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b)^2}{|\mathbf a||\mathbf b|}$$
The reason to use $\cos^2$ is to ignore the antiparallel case.